# pulling changes from a renamed git repo to my new git repo

Tags: gitlab, git-merge, git-pull

I cloned a repo (repo A) and then renamed the repo to my own repo (repo B). Repo A gets updated from time to time by the owner, please how can I pull these new changes to my own repo (Repo B)? Thank you for your help

Comment: I think you meant 'forked' instead of 'cloned'? Your repo B is on your local machine or on a server (I assume Gitlab since you tagged your question as [gitlab])?

Comment: the project (repo A) that I cloned is on github. since I am working on gitlab, I renamed the cloned repo A to a newly created repo B on gitlab. the changes that I make I push it to the new repo B on gitlab. But I also want to pull any new changes made by repo A's owner into my repo B.